# How to set up imports correctly in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import, modulenotfounderror

I have the following directory structure for my python project.

```
.
├── AUTHORS.rst
├── CONTRIBUTING.rst
├── HISTORY.rst
├── MANIFEST.in
├── Makefile
├── README.rst
├── __pycache__
│   └── test.cpython-310.pyc
├── docs
├── logs
├── python_server_copy
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── cli.py
│   ├── copy.py
│   ├── python_server_copy.py
│   ├── test.py
│   └── utils.py
├── requirements_dev.txt
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── tests
└── tox.ini
```

This is `click` based command line application. I have imports defined in the files with the  package name. For example:

In `copy.py`:

```
from python_server_copy.utils import get_project_root
```

However these imports don't work when I am testing. I get `ModuleNotFound` Error when running the files as a script directly. I have to remove the `python_server_copy` package name every time I am testing. Everything works fine if it is run as command line click application.

I need suggestions on how to test it properly and handle imports. TIA

I am using python 3.7.11 if that is useful.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a script in Python, its directory is gonna be added to the `sys.path`(where Python looks for modules/packages). Now when you run your `copy.py` directly, `Parents.../python_server_copy` is added, plus some other default paths for site-packages and etc.

Therefore there is no `python_server_copy` module/package *inside* `Parents.../python_server_copy` directory(or any other paths).

Instead, you need to add "*its*" parent which happens to be your project's root directory so that it can find your `python_server_copy` package.

You have couple of options:

```py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, <Path to root>)
```

Or just import the `utils` directly because it's already findable:

```py
from utils import get_project_root
```

Or lastly, since you're just testing, run your script with `PYTHONPATH` environment variable:

```bash
PYTHONPATH="abs-path-to-root" python copy.py
```

Comment: Hi @S.B This works fine but the problem is if I run my click application then I get module not found error again so I again have to add the package names before the imports for it to work. Is there a permanent solution?

Comment: @VanditGoel Which of the three options did you try?